# UIView's frame is not shown updated with UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview, frame, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a subview in a viewController to which I added a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. I'd like to expand such subview when the user drags it down, so I'm trying to handle the gesture recognizer status like this:

```
@objc func panning(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: view)

    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        originalFrame = self.mySubview.frame
    } else if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        if translation.y > 0 {
            var newFrame = originalFrame
            newFrame.size.height += translation.y
            mySubview.frame = newFrame
        }
    }
}
```

when I set a breakpoint at `mySubview.frame = newFrame`, I see that `newFrame` is updated with the translation. However, I don't see the frame changes in the screen, the subview looks always like at the beginning.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 2):

PanGesture is a tricky, but working with it is very interesting...

I am assuming you have added pan gesture correctly to the view. So writing down the handling of the gesture only.

```
  func handlePanGesture(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    var translatedPoint: CGPoint = gesture.translation(in: self.superview)

    let playerCenterX: CGFloat = (gesture.view?.center.x)! + translatedPoint.x
    let playerCenterY: CGFloat = (gesture.view?.center.y)! + translatedPoint.y

    translatedPoint = CGPoint.init(x: playerCenterX,
                                   y: playerCenterY)

    gesture.view?.center = translatedPoint
    gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.superview)

}
```

Important thing is that you set its translation back to zero every time at the end of gesture movement.

As per your requirement change this `self.superview` and use the coordinates to update your view frame...

Answer (score 0):

If your view's frame is set by the autolayout you should update constraints, not the view's frame itself.